# How to send Ctrl + a then d in Expect

Tags: expect

So I am trying to spawn a shell to a remote server then make a screen run some commands and then detach from said screen by doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set server [lindex $argv 0]

spawn s "$server"
expect "#" { send "screen -S test\r" }
expect "#" { send \someescapeheretoreplicate ctrl + a then d to tell screen to detach }
interact
```

But I have no idea what those escape sequences are called so am unable to look up a table of them or what not.

Comment: i am not quite sure. i think control+a is recognized as a sequence of 3 key presses. tha's why in some console, you will see `^]]A`. i tried to find it but i am out of luck. i think what i need to do here is to send the sequence.

Comment: Was able to resolve by changing the control character when generating screen: expect "#" { send "screen -e xy -S $ticket\r" }

Comment: You can control screen by running commands - for example, start it with `screen -S test` then detach it with `screen -d test`. (You can run the command in expect using `exec`.)

Answer (score 5):

If I recall:

```
send "\x01"; send "d"
```

Where `\x01` is the value of Ctrl-A

Comment: need ctrl a not ctrl A

Comment: No it did not work because i need lowercase a not uppercase a but I found an alternative solution. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

for Ctrl+A

```
send "\x01"
```

for Ctrl+D

```
send "\x04"
```